# Android Intent pass Object between different different apps

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have this Activity (the `MainActivity`, from package package `com.example.myapplication`) that receives an `Intent` of class "`BeanValidacion`".

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle willirex = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(willirex!=null)
        {
            BeanValidacion datos = (BeanValidacion) willirex.get("paramIn");

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,datos.getIdNumber(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
```

And I want to call it with a different APK (package `com.adon.intents`) and send an `Intent`, as I do with String `Intent`s, but this time, I want to send an object of class "`BeanValidacion`":

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BeanValidacion datos = new BeanValidacion();
        datos.setIdNumber("12345");
        Intent next = new Intent();
        next.setClassName("com.example.myapplication", "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity");
        next.putExtra("paramIn", datos);

        startActivity(next);

    }
```

When I execute the `com.adon.intents` APK to send the intent, I got this error on `com.example.myapplication`:

> ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = com.adon.intents.BeanValidacion

In this line:

`Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,datos.getIdNumber(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

This doesn't happen when sending just a `String`, but I am having problems solving this one.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `BeanValidacion.java` file in the exact package hierarchy `com.adon.intents.BeanValidacion` on the second app. Also, both classes should have the same `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: This is my package hierarchy: http://imgur.com/3ZcDrJ1

I am not sure what can I do to get it right, naming the same apps the same?

Comment: As I said before, you should create packages `com.adon.intents` and move the `BeanValidacion` in it. I'm seeing in the left window that you put the `BeanValidacion` class into the `com.example.myapplication` which is not the correct place.

Comment: Ok I have solved the first issue as you said, now I got: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.adon.intents.BeanValidacion)`

and `com.adon.intents.BeanValidacion; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5379389730745689250, local class serialVersionUID = -417798800317482157`  and you said previously, do you know how to solve it? Regards

https://imgur.com/a/Rc0Sjfw

Comment: In one of your projects, the Android Studio should make a warning to add `serialVersionUID` for the BeanValidacion class. Press alt + enter and let the IDE generate a `serialVersionUID` for it. Then copy this line to the other project.

Comment: Or assign a long number to it yourself, like `public static final long serialVersionUID = 40L;`. Now add this line to the both project.

Comment: Note that if the properties in `serialVersionUID` are not primitive, the class of them should implement the Serializable interface too.

Comment: Dude, it works, that was legit, thank you very much! =)

Comment: just to know: What happens if I cannot change the "serialVersionUID" of the one I'm calling ??? Because I can't change the code of the one that receives the Intent in my real case

Comment: So you should check its source code and use the `serialVersionUID` of it in your side.